# Error handling in Batch script when a batch script failed

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file, sync

I am trying to run a batch file via a batch script and when the batch file is failing I want to print an error as `Sync failed` if it passes I want to print a message as `Sync success`

So when my script fails:
its prints `Sync failed`
but when my script(get_files.bat) success it prints:
`Sync failed`
`Sync success`
So I dont know why its print both `Sync failed` & `Sync success` when my script(get_files.bat) passed successfully

**My code:**

```
echo Sync Starts
cd C:\Users\Common\Files
call get_files.bat
if  errorlevel 1 goto ERROR
echo SUCCESSFUL

:ERROR
echo Failed
cmd /k
exit /b 1
```

Comment: a label is just a "goto destination". It doesn't magically stop the code flow (actually it just is ignored). You need to put a `goto :eof` or `exit /b 0` after `echo SUCCESSFUL` to stop the code flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a EOF label at the end of the script and when the script works goto EOF

```
echo Sync Starts
cd C:\Users\Common\Files
call get_files.bat
if  errorlevel 1 goto ERROR
echo SUCCESSFUL
goto EOF 

:ERROR
echo Failed
cmd /k
exit /b 1

:EOF
```

or instead, you can exit with 0 code

```
echo Sync Starts
cd C:\Users\Common\Files
call get_files.bat
if  errorlevel 1 goto ERROR
echo SUCCESSFUL
exit /b 0

:ERROR
echo Failed
cmd /k
exit /b 1
```

Comment: I think it should be `:EXIT` instead of `EXIT:`

Comment: `exit /b 0` instead of `goto EXIT` would do the job likewise.

Comment: EXIT is a COMMAND. Avoid creating labels that are also commands. A better solution would be to use GOTO :EOF

Answer (score 1):

```bat
@echo off

echo\Sync Starts & cd /d "C:\Users\Common\Files"

call "get_files.cmd"|findstr /be 0 >nul && goto %:^) || goto %:^(

%:^)
:: your code/commands come here to refer to an SUCCESSFUL event 
timeout 3 | exit /b 0 | echo\SUCCESSFUL & goto :EOF

%:^(
:: your code/commands come here to refer to an Failed event 
timeout 3 | echo\If you see this, your "get_files.cmd" Failed
exit /b 1 | goto :EOF
```

---

You will need to align the bats, so that it is possible for the interaction of one to inform the result of the execution to the other bat, it is no use editing a `goto :label/:eof` only on the bat that calls the execution of the other, it will not return an accurate/precisely execution of the successful occurrence, one or more errors.

Your script is designed to take actions when ***`returning 0`*** or ***`returning non 0`*** for the execution of your other file batch, but understand that it doesn't work well for bat files, with **`call | if !errorlevel!`** you will not get an accurate return the errorlevel to the same way that you get from an executable (or internal/external command), which also applies *"in part"*, for some cmd.exe/executed in blocks `(like dir file_1.txt file2.txt)`.

Your command interpreter (`cmd.exe`), will handle the return/errorlevel of that executable, individually, command by command, a for some cases, in blocks().

For a **`.cmd|.bat`** file, the cmd.exe will treat each execution separately, and you will get the `return 0` or `return non 0`, just for the `last command` in this get_files.bat

- About using `errorlevel` in `.bat` vs `.cmd` file...

  - ```bat
    Old style .bat Batch files vs .cmd Batch scripts.
    There is a key difference between the way .CMD and
    .BAT batch files set errorlevels
    ```
  - ```bat
    A .BAT batch script running the 'new' internal commands:
    APPEND, ASSOC, PATH, PROMPT, FTYPE and SET will only set ERRORLEVEL
    if an error occurs. So if you have two commands in the batch script
    and the first fails, the ERRORLEVEL will remain set even after the
    second command succeeds.
    ```


    <sup>Source linked to **ss64.com**</sup>
- What you can do to give a precise status of the execution status, would be to send `bat` variables to the other batch, or at least some string in the output, thus replacing the errorlevel, but it requires an edition of your bat for one version more aligned with the execution to respond to the bat that originated the execution call, something that responds predictively to the error event or not.

  - ```bat
    EXIT
    Close the current batch script, exit the current subroutine or
    close the CMD.EXE session, optionally setting an errorlevel..
    ```


    <sup>Source linked to **ss64.com**</sup>

<kbd>***[`Get_Files.bat`](https://superuser.com/questions/1618682/error-handling-in-batch-script-when-a-batch-script-failed/1619100#1619100)***</kbd>

```bat
@echo off 

set "_error=0"

command_normal 1
command_normal 2
command_normal 3 

command_critical 1 || set "_error=1"
command_critical 2 || set "_error=2"
command_critical 3 || set "_error=3"

command_normal 4 
.....
command_normal n
..... 
command_critical n || set "_error=n"

exit /b | echo\%_error%
```

<kbd>***[`The_Batch_caller.bat`](https://superuser.com/questions/1618682/error-handling-in-batch-script-when-a-batch-script-failed/1619100#1619100)***</kbd>

```bat
@echo off

echo\Sync Starts 
cd /d "C:\Users\Common\Files"

call "get_files.cmd"|findstr /be 0 >nul && goto :Next_CMDs || goto :Error

:Next_CMDs
:: your code/commands come here to refer to an SUCCESSFUL event 
exit /b 0 | echo\SUCCESSFUL & goto :EOF

:Error
:: your code/commands come here to refer to an Failed event 
exit /b 1 | echo\Failed & goto :EOF
```

---

- Using: **`call file.bat/.cmd`** using **`findstr /begin /end`** with **`0`** and operator **`&&`** and/or **`||`**

Editing your bat to make use of a control over the results of your commands using operator **`||`** (`return non 0`), where you can define your own `errolevel` based on the result of each *"critical execution"*, also making use of the **`exit /b`** command with your errorlevel predefined, which will be captured by the calling bat and the relevant actions will be performed accurately.

```bat
"get_files.cmd" | findstr /be 0              &&           goto :Next_CMDs
          your_command                    (if return 0)      run this command too

call  "get_files.cmd" | findstr /be 0        ||           goto :ERRORs
          your_command                   (if return non 0)   run this command too
```

- Using `&&(commands) ||(commands)`:

```bat
 your_command | findstr /be 0  && (
                                    return 0
                                    rem :: more command here
                                    rem :: more command here
                                    rem :: ...
                                 ) || (
                                    return non 0
                                    rem :: more command here
                                    rem :: more command here
                                    rem :: ...
                                 )
```

---

---

**Additional resources:**

- [`Call ?`](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html)
- [`Echo /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html)
- [`Exit /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/exit.html)
- [`Timeout /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html)
- [`FindSTR /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)
- [Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

  - `|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.
- [Conditional Execution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)

  - [`||`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html) and [`&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)
- [`Errolevel /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html)
- [`Local Environment | Function` | Also Refer: `Goto :EOF`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-functions.html)

  - [`Setlocal`](https://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html) & [`Endlocal`](https://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html)
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/6819406)

Comment: Your `%:^)` / `%:^(` labels made me think I was having a stroke for a moment, then my brain caught up and I laughed for a good minute.  :-)

Comment: @TiStrga thkx... has several variations **`%:ˆV  %:ˆ!   %:ˆ0    %:ˆ[   %:ˆ?  %:ˆ/ `**